# Setting input props based off another prop state?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield, react-props

I would like to know how to update inputProps in textfield based off another prop,

```
  <TextField
  name={props.name}
  value={props.vals}
  inputProps={{autocapitalize:"characters", textTransform:"uppercase"}}
  onChange={props.getStuff}
/>
```

I also have a prop that is designed to check if the textfield should display everything in all caps or not !

```
setAllCapital = true
```

I would like it so if setAllCapital is true the input props is given the autocap and text transform, but if its false then it is not given anything.

What is the convention/best way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the **input props** based on condition

```
<TextField
  name={props.name}
  value={props.vals}
  inputProps={props.setAllCapital ? {autocapitalize:"characters", textTransform:"uppercase"} : "whatever value you want"}
  onChange={props.getStuff}
/>
```

Now whenever your setAllCapital is false, you won't be sending autocap and textTransform to TextField.

**Edit:**

And a much more concise way would be

```
<TextField
  name={props.name}
  value={props.vals}
  inputProps={props.setAllCapital && {autocapitalize:"characters", textTransform:"uppercase"}}
  onChange={props.getStuff}
/>
```

Now your input props will be undefined if setAllCapital is false

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to check the condition inline and pass the props. If props.setAllCapital is false then nothing gets passed to inputProps.

```
<TextField
      name={props.name}
      value={props.vals}
      inputProps={props.setAllCapital ? {autocapitalize:"characters", 
      textTransform:"uppercase"}:undefined}
      onChange={props.getStuff}
    />
```